# Slicing dfs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

i have a list which contains dates. It looks like that:

```
    [datetime.date(1994, 2, 4),
     datetime.date(1994, 3, 22),
     datetime.date(1994, 4, 18),
     datetime.date(1994, 5, 17),
     datetime.date(1994, 8, 16)
     ...]
```

and the pandas df which looks like:

```
    Date    USD_I
0   1971-01-04  100.0000
1   1971-01-05  99.9700
2   1971-01-06  99.9500
3   1971-01-07  99.9400
4   1971-01-08  99.9300
5   1971-01-11  99.9100
6   1971-01-12  99.8900
7   1971-01-13  99.9000
8   1971-01-14  99.8300

and so on
```

I'm trying to build a new df which should look like:

```
     1994-02-04 1994-03-22 1994-04-18 ...
-2
-1
 0
 1
 2
```

Value for the column '1994-02-04' in a row '0' should be the value for that date from first df ('USD_I' column). The value for the row '-1' should be the value for the day before, and the value for row '1' should be value for the next day and so on. Simply the columns are the values from the list and the values for the new df are slices of data from the first df.

I am trying to do that for the second day and i still got errors with indexing and was unable to find solution online. I will really appreciate any help and hint how to deal with it.

---

I'm trying to do it with ('result' is the name of the final df):

```
for i in list:
    result[i] = df[df['Date']==i]['USD_I']
```

That gave me a dataframe with dates as columns names which is good but first row have only the value for the first date and others are NaN so i deleted this whole row and try:

```
for i in result:
    for x in range(-2,3):
        result.loc[x,i] = df.loc[(df[df['Date']==i].index.values+x),'USD_I']
```

But this gave me *ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series*.

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you using `datetime.timedelta` to add/subtract days?

Comment: in your output dataframe, what should the values be? It looks like only an index and columns

Comment: @Marmaduke i have added more details to the post and the way i am trying to do this.

Comment: @MattR Value for the column '1994-02-04' in a row '0' should be the value for that date from first df ('USD_I' column). The value for the row '-1' should be the value for the day before, and the value for row '1' should be value for the next day and so on. Simply the columns are the values from the list and the values for the new df are slices of data from the first df.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into pandas pivot method (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot).  This will allow you to make the dates the column names.  From there you can use pd.timedelta (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) to get a datetime for either the day prior or post the current date.  You can then use this new datetime object to reindex into the dataframe to get the proper day.

I believe there is probably an easier way to do this by using the shift method, but this assumes that you have a value for everyday and that they are in order.

Comment: I'm making mistake somewhere in the last loop, no matter if i use days or index values.  I changed last line of the loop to  result.loc[x,i] = df[df['Date']== (i + dt.timedelta(days=x))]['USD_I'] but it gave me ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series. Do you know what am i doing wrong? I am completely lost with it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's done. I made a list of index numbers and then it goes smoothly. I tried it before but my mistake was to use list.append instead of list.extend. Thanks for your support.